Arduino seems to be reading incorrect analog I/O. Am I doing something wrong?
I am using an ATTiny88 to measure temperature using a 470 ohm thermistor attached to port A3 on the Arduino.  The thermistor is attached in series with an 1870 ohm resistor connected to Vcc.  At room temperature, the voltage across the thermistor is roughly 1.5V, and Vcc is 5.1V, so that calculates to be a digital conversion of about 0x012C.  When I query the Arduino, however, it is returning 0x0288.  Unless I am missing something, that corresponds to over 3 volts.  Of course, the value varies over time, but the point is the returned value is about a factor of 2 off.  That number is suspicious, but it may not be exactly a factor of 2.  As a sanity check, 0x012C is very close to what I should be getting according to a reference thermometer given the thermistor's resistance curve.  This is the Arduino code:
#include <Wire.h>

#define Cool    0   // Peltier Cooler ON = HIGH
#define POK 1   // Power Failure IN
#define Fan 9   // Fan Relay ON = HIGH
#define PiCtl   14  // Raspberry Pi Power
#define ADDR1   15  // I2C Address 1
#define ADDR2   16  // I2C Address 2
#define SCL 23  // I2C Clock
#define SDA 24  // I2C Data

#define PTC 16  // Thermocouple Analog IN
#define FanT    655 // Fan Threshold
#define CoolT   895 // Cooling Threshold
#define DelSt   120000  // Startup delay

int I2C;
bool True = 1;
bool False = 0;
float Temp;
bool FanSet;
bool PowerFail;
bool Responded;
unsigned long timeStamp;
unsigned long heartBeat;

union Response {
    struct {
        int Temperature;    // 2 bytes
        unsigned long Living;   // 4 bytes
        uint8_t Command;    // 1 byte
        uint8_t FanValue;   // 1 byte
        uint8_t CoolStat;   // 1 byte
        uint8_t PowerStat;  // 1 byte
        uint8_t padding;    // 1 byte
    };
    uint8_t bytes[11];
};
union Response Reply;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(Cool, OUTPUT);      // Set Cooling Pin
    digitalWrite(Cool, 0);      // Turn Cooling Off
    pinMode(POK, INPUT);        // Set Power Sense Pin
    pinMode(Fan, OUTPUT);       // Set Fan Pin
    analogWrite(Fan, 0);        // Turn Fan Off
    pinMode(PiCtl, OUTPUT);     // Set Pi Power Pin
    digitalWrite(PiCtl, LOW);   // Turn Raspberry Pi On
    pinMode(ADDR1, INPUT_PULLUP);   // Address Offset 0 or 1
    pinMode(ADDR2, INPUT_PULLUP);   // Address Offset 0 or 2
    I2C = (2 * digitalRead(ADDR2)) + digitalRead(ADDR1) + 8;    // Set I2C address 8 - 11
    Wire.begin(I2C);        // Initialize I2C Communications
    Wire.onRequest(requestEvent);   // Call requestEvent when data requested
    Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);   // Call receiveEvent when data received
    Reply.PowerStat = 1;        // Reset Power Status
    Reply.FanValue = 1;     // Set Fan Status On
    Reply.CoolStat = 0;     // Set Cool Status Off
    delay (DelSt);
}

void HeartBeat()
{
    if (millis() - heartBeat > 30000)
    {
        digitalWrite(PiCtl, HIGH);  // Turn Raspberry Pi Off
        delay (10000);
        digitalWrite(PiCtl, LOW);   // Turn Raspberry Pi On
        delay (DelSt);
        heartBeat = millis();       // Set the living time
    }
}

void TempCheck()
{
    Reply.Temperature = analogRead(PTC);
    if (Reply.Temperature > CoolT)
    {
        Reply.FanValue = 1;     // Set Fan Status On
        Reply.CoolStat = 1;     // Set Cool Status On
        digitalWrite(Cool, 1);      // Turn Cooling On
        analogWrite(Fan, 255);      // Turn Fan On
    }
    else if (Reply.Temperature > FanT)
    {
        Reply.FanValue = 1;     // Set Fan Status On
        Reply.CoolStat = 0;     // Set Cool Status Off
        digitalWrite(Cool, 0);      // Turn Cooling Off
        analogWrite(Fan, 255);      // Turn Fan On
    }
    else
    {
        Reply.FanValue = 0;     // Set Fan Status Off
        Reply.CoolStat = 0;     // Set Cool Status Off
        digitalWrite(Cool, 0);      // Turn Cooling Off
        analogWrite(Fan, 0);        // Turn Fan Off
    }
}

void PowerCheck()
{
    bool Power = digitalRead(POK);
    if (Power)
    {
        if (PowerFail)
        {
            PowerFail = False;  // Reset Power Failure Variable
        }
        digitalWrite(PiCtl, LOW);   // Turn Raspberry Pi On
        Reply.Command = 0;      // Reset shutdown command
        Reply.PowerStat = 1;        // Reset Power Status
    }
    else
    {
        timeStamp = millis();       // Reset Timer
        int Iterations = 0;     // Reset Time Counter
        while (!Power)
        {
            if (millis() - timeStamp > 5000)
            {
                timeStamp = millis();       // Reset Timer
                Power = digitalRead(POK);   // Check Power Input
                Iterations += 1;        // Set Time Counter
                Reply.PowerStat = 0;        // Set Power Status
                if (Iterations > 24)
                {
                    digitalWrite(PiCtl, HIGH);  // Turn Raspberry Pi Off
                    analogWrite(Fan, 0);        // Turn Fan Off
                }
                else if (Iterations > 12)
                {
                    Reply.Command = 1;  // Set Shutdown Command
                }
            }

        }
        Reply.PowerStat = 1;        // Set Power Status
        Reply.Command = 0;
        digitalWrite(PiCtl, LOW);   // Turn Raspberry Pi On
    }
}

// Function that executes whenever data is requested by master
void requestEvent()
{
    Reply.Living = millis() - heartBeat;    // Set the responded time
    heartBeat = millis();           // Reset the heartbeat
    Wire.write(Reply.bytes, sizeof Reply);  // respond with message as expected by master
    Responded = True;           // Set the responded variable
}

// Function that executes whenever data is received from master
void receiveEvent(int howMany)
{
    while (Wire.available()) { // loop through all but the last
        char c = Wire.read(); // receive byte as a character
        }
    Responded = True;           // Set the responded variable
    Reply.Living = millis();        // Set the responded time
}

void loop()
{
    PowerCheck();
    TempCheck();
    HeartBeat();
    long int dSeconds = millis();       // Number of milliseconds since powerup
    while (millis() < dSeconds + 1000){}    // Delay 1 second before looping
}

When I issue the command i2ctransfer -y 1 r10@0x0a I get:
0x88 0x02 0x45 0x13 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x01 0x00

all of which is expected given the state of the board with the exception of the fact the first two bytes should be more like "0x2c 0x01".  The value of 0x0288 calculates to nearly 62C, and the board is more like 30C.


it is unclear how the resistors are connected... please add a diagram ... you can click on the button that looks like a circuit ... draw diagram, then click save and insert ... or draw a diagram on paper and insert a picture

The 1870 ohm resistor is connected to Vcc and the PTC to ground, with the Arduino connected to the common point.  How else would a voltage divider be designed?  I am also not exactly sure how it is relevant.  The actual voltage is 1.5V, while the reported voltage is 3V, regardless of the circuit design.

if you read your question, then you'll see that you said nothing about connecting to ground

Is your problem to do with an analog read of a voltage ? Is this the statment which yields the incorrect result analogRead(PTC) ? Is this: #define PTC 16 also pin A3 which you have referred to in your text ? Is it also shared with this: #define ADDR2  16 ?. If you are reading an analog pin, what is the relevance of this in your text i2ctransfer -y 1 r10@0x0a ? Try applying various voltages between 0 and 5v (using resistor divider networks) to A3 to see if you get the range between 0 and 1024. If not, look at the voltage reference configuration.

The pin numbering in your diagram looks odd in that it appears to be the underside of the IC and does not seem to correspond with an ATTiny88 which has either 28 or 32 pins depending on the package. State which Arduino core you are using so, for example, it is possible to match pin A3 to the definitions in your program.

This is the board:  https://www.amazon.com/QCCAN-ATTINY88-Development-ATmega328-Compatible/dp/B0B71FLZ4X/ref=sr_1_3?crid=1WPMLC2L6NQKB&dib=eyJ2IjoiMSJ9.NEwnS1IVFmzprb50H5C-tug_7yTOqnCJcN2fRd6O46ZF_CWO_tpuS0hHp5AWR-JioRVlo6yxRd1hjeOYd66OEXclEkvK7GWM87rNu05UnZeJyjPclnymcEI4Ao8TcID9pAJwkXjt6sG7Wwx4Yff1L5Iaw9hOi5LWoAdqs8fx8B_XfBPPqKuLMGSA_59bwGIjNXNdFCuL2bsO4ioCsFxu8LM6nXwmKQlUaiqKLO4jCPI.SgMxou8CSExZ5fwOckECv7thaKj5zJuVx-h3W3xXfjM&dib_tag=se&keywords=attiny88&qid=1731339694&sprefix=attiny%2Caps%2C143&sr=8-3

I thought it was clear.  I am reading a number of pins, one of them being an analog pin, as well as the elapsed time since the last request from the external host and storing the values in the structure "Reply".  I retrieve those values to the remote host by issuing the command i2ctransfer -y 1 r10@0x0a in a BASH script.   I don't have an easy way to vary the voltage on the pin at the moment, but the new PC board prototype is arriving in a few days, which will make it easier.
